# SQL Select Based On Available Server / Tables

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Shared Dataset within an SSRS Report that tests to see if the linked server is available before attempting to retrieve the table.

What I didn't cater for is sometimes they do a data rebuild (its part of the sector specific software) that drops all the tables including the one if reference.

So I'm getting an issue whereby the linked server is active but it cannot find the table I'm after.

How can I have this query both test the linked server AND see if the table is available and if neither are true run the 'Catch' statement I have at the bottom.

The table I need to test for is

**[FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy**

```
BEGIN TRY
exec sp_testlinkedserver [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK];
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM InfoCentre.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Error Retrieving Bracknell Brands'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM InfoCentre.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
END CATCH
```

I have tried doing this

```
BEGIN TRY
exec sp_testlinkedserver [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK];
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'ic_brpolicy')
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Table Doesnt Exist',16,1)
END
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'icp_brpolicy')
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Table Doesnt Exist',16,1)
END
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM InfoCentre.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Error Retrieving Bracknell Brands'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM InfoCentre.dbo.ic_brpolicy
WHERE   Brand IS NOT NULL
END CATCH
```

Comment: Your code looks well, what is your problem? If the server is not accessible, it goes to cath block. If the table is not accessible, it goes too

Comment: The only strange thing I see is that you have a *user* table in *master*

Comment: @sepupic See the issue is with the IF NOT EXISTS, it still tries to select from the Table so its not going to the CATCH statement.

Comment: No, I've tried it with the existing linked server and not existing table, it goes to catch and prints Table Doesnt Exist

Comment: @sepupic I return "The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK" does not contain the table ""First_ICP"."dbo"."ic_brpolicy"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table."

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it when I go not to master but to another db that does not exist. So you should wrap it in the dynamic code

Comment: The thing is too strange: how can you get that error if master database ALWAYS exists and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES also?

Comment: It means only one thing: the table does exist and so you do not go to catch when controlling it in master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, but it exists in MASTER database. But why do you do SELECT from the table residing in InfoCentre????

Answer (score 0):

The error here is:

first you check the existance of table in **master** database:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'ic_brpolicy')
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Table Doesnt Exist',16,1)
END
```

but the table exists in master, so you have no error and do not go to `catch`-block

But then you do `SELECT` not from `master.dbo.ic_brpolicy` but from `First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy` 
and the table does not exist or you do not have permission on it.

You should check for existance in the `First_ICP` database like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].First_ICP.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'ic_brpolicy')
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Table Doesnt Exist',16,1)
END
```

To catch compilation error you can use dynamic code like this:

```
begin try 
   exec('select top 1 * from InfoCentre.dbo.ic_brpolicy');

   exec('select top 1 * from [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK].First_ICP.dbo.ic_brpolicy');


begin catch
   select error_message();
end catch
```

Comment: Nope still errors out for me dude :-/ same error as above.

Comment: Did you change "master" to the db you are interested in?

Comment: This means the table exists but you have no permission, wait a minute I'll update my answer using dynamic code. Or you should use fn_my_permissions() to check for permissions

Comment: Hi bud, InfoCentre doesn't exist as a DB on [FIRST-W2K12-SQL.HQ.FIRST.CO.UK], its on the server I'm running the code and First_ICP is on the Linked Server.